# SoapUI - How to copy property (with groovy script) to another property

Tags: properties, soapui

I have a Test Suite with several tests (REST services). For several attributes, I need to fill Timestamp into them. I use property (myDateTime) with this value:

`${=def now = new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm")}`

This works fine, but I need to use the same value several times, during longer period of time.

So my idea was to generate the myDateTime at the beginning of the test run and then copy it to another property, which will contain this one time generated value (staticDateTime), and then use this staticDateTime in requests.

Problem is, when I try to use **Property Transfer** step, it copies whole string mentioned above, without evaluating it and inserting only result value.

Can someone help me to copy the property properly or maybe come up with another solution to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a Groovy script step. There are various levels of properties, depending on the scope you want the property to have.

Setting values:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("propName", propValue)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("propName", propValue)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("PropName", propValue)
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue("propName", propValue)
```

Accessing the values:

```
def myVal = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("propName")
def myVal = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("propName")
def myVal = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("PropName")
def myVal = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("propName")
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am unable to run it. I have my property myDateTime defined on TestSuite, so I think I have to use second row from your example.
So when I run line> `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("Testing", myDateTime)`, I 'got response: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myDateTime for class: Script 44 error at line: 1`

Comment: This works on SoapUI Open Source 5.6.0 with Java 11: `def myDateTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm")
log.info myDateTime
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("Testing", myDateTime)
def readVal = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("Testing")
log.info readVal`

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Sorry for not getting it on first try :)